# How to add a group and restrict permission on group level by Enable Project-based security on Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, authorization, openldap

The LDAP integration is done successfully but when I try to apply project based security to the pipeline level it's not working as expected it is able to identify the group so in that case LDAP is working but the members of the group aren't able to see the pipelines for which the permission are granted.
Authorization method used Project based Matrix Authorization Strategy[image: PFA for reference where the members in the group contractors are not able see this particular job]
I'm stuck at this point it would be a great help if I could get the solution.

I have tried changing the LDAP configuration in Jenkins but it's of no use. I think the problem is not with the LDAP and there is something beyond that I'm missing.

Comment: In the above attached screenshot members from the group contrators are not able to see the jobs

Answer (score 0):

You must select `Inherit permissions from parent ACL` in Inheritance Strategy for getting group and adding permissions in your jobs.

Comment: Even Though I choose Inherit permission from ACL It's not working.